# Ubuntu 16.04 Window Spread is glitchy and makes the screen freeze

Tags: unity, 16.04, unity-tweak-tool

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. When I turn off **window spread** from Unity Tweak Tool then try to turn it back on, I'm always geting glitches and a frozen screen when I activate window spread. Is there any fix for this?

Fixed now: restarting Unity fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. First I used the answer from edanpose and thanks to it Unity stopped freezing, but after I pressed <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> the screen wallpaper was showing up for about a second and then everything was back to normal, but spread was not working.

Then after reading [this Ubuntu Forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218319) I installed compizconfig-settings-manager (CCSM) in order to check whether the scale plugin is enabled (as I understand it is related with window scaling used in window thread).

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then in CCSM Window Management, one can enable **Scale window**. What is interesting in my system is that it was already enabled, but when I left CCSM, window spread (<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) started working without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Now Unity glitches but does not freeze anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by clicking on `Restore defaults` button

[image]